# Joomla 4 ajax php file in component, $application missing LanguageFactoryInterface::class

Tags: joomla-4.x, ajax, language

In Joomla4 i am creating a ajax.php file for getting json results

```
// Boot the DI container
$container = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer();

$container->alias('session.web', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias('session', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias('JSession', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\CMS\Session\Session::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\Session\Session::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\CMS\Application\WebApplication::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\Session\SessionInterface::class, 'session.web.site');

$app = $container->get(\Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::class);

\Joomla\CMS\Factory::$application = $app;

dd($app);

^ Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication {#156 ▼
  #config: Joomla\Registry\Registry {#157 ▶}
  #logger: Joomla\CMS\Log\DelegatingPsrLogger {#173 ▶}
  -dispatcher: Joomla\Event\Dispatcher {#142 ▶}
  #input: Joomla\CMS\Input\Input {#158 ▶}
  +charSet: "utf-8"
  +mimeType: "text/html"
  +httpVersion: "1.1"
  +modifiedDate: null
  +client: Joomla\Application\Web\WebClient {#162 ▶}
  #response: Laminas\Diactoros\Response {#163 ▶}
  -cacheable: false
  -responseMap: array:61 [▶]
  #document: null
  #language: null
  #identity: null
  -userFactory: Joomla\CMS\User\UserFactory {#185 ▶}
  #docOptions: []
  +scope: null
  #clientId: 0
  #messageQueue: []
  #name: "site"
  #profiler: Joomla\CMS\Profiler\Profiler {#172 ▶}
  #template: null
  #pathway: null
  #authenticationPluginType: "authentication"
  -container: Joomla\DI\Container {#20 ▶}
  #session: Joomla\CMS\Session\Session {#184 ▶}
  #language_filter: false
  #detect_browser: false
}
```

how do i get the language interface class?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need an instance of `Joomla\CMS\Language\LanguageFactoryInterface`?